# Restarting X in CentOS 5

Tags: linux, terminal, x-server

I went to a CentOS terminal, and someone was logged in doing work. I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to try to get to my own session so I could check something. When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get back, X did not come back up and gave a bunch of error messages.

Is this a bug? Did that other user just lose all the work they had running? It seems like if I had to kill all X and do a `startx` again, he would lose everything running in the terminals and other GUI apps, right?

Answer (score 5):

I admittedly know nothing about CentOS, but usually <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd> are reserved for TTYs; X sessions don't start until <kbd>F7</kbd>. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> should get you back to the first X session

Comment: May possibly be Ctrl+Alt+F5 as well (:  depends, depends.